# Issue in editing web app bot cortana channel

Tags: artificial-intelligence, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have created a new Web APP BOT And I am trying to edit the Cortana Channel but I am getting the following error.

> "Failed to register Cortana developer".

I am not sure why am i getting this.

The below is the screenshot of the error message (Error Message when I try to edit channel)

[image]

Is anybody have any idea about this please

Thanks

Comment: Check the upper right hand corner to see if the account via azure portal is the same one that created the bot and the channel.  You will see this error if, for example, you created the bot with one subscription, then assigned another MSA via IAM, and then tried to edit the channel with the other MSA.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?